# Dynamically mixin a base class to an instance in Python

Tags: python, oop, mixins

Is it possible to add a base class to an object instance (not a class!) at runtime? Something along the lines of how `Object#extend` works in Ruby:

```
class Gentleman(object):
  def introduce_self(self):
    return "Hello, my name is %s" % self.name

class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

p = Person("John")
# how to implement this method?
extend(p, Gentleman)
p.introduce_self() # => "Hello, my name is John"
```

Comment: Uuuuurrgghhh!!!!! Changing an instance without changing the class is a recipe for disaster. The nicer way to do this is to make a subclass of `Person` and mix `Gentleman` into that.

Comment: @katrielalex: Probably you're right in most cases. Nevertheless, I need that functionality because I want to add functionality to a third-party library whose interface I cannot change. I had to choose between mixins or the proxy pattern, of which the latter I don't like very much.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This dynamically defines a new class `GentlePerson`, and reassigns `p`'s class to it:

```
class Gentleman(object):
  def introduce_self(self):
    return "Hello, my name is %s" % self.name

class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

p = Person("John")
p.__class__ = type('GentlePerson',(Person,Gentleman),{})
print(p.introduce_self())
# "Hello, my name is John"
```

Per your request, this modifies `p`'s bases, but does not alter `p`'s original class `Person`. Thus, other instances of `Person` are unaffected (and would raise an `AttributeError` if `introduce_self` were called).

---

Although it was not directly asked in the question, I'll add for googlers and curiosity seekers, that it is also possible to dynamically change a class's bases but (AFAIK) only if the class does not inherit directly from `object`:

```
class Gentleman(object):
  def introduce_self(self):
    return "Hello, my name is %s" % self.name

class Base(object):pass
class Person(Base):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

p = Person("John")
Person.__bases__=(Gentleman,object,)
print(p.introduce_self())
# "Hello, my name is John"

q = Person("Pete")
print(q.introduce_self())
# Hello, my name is Pete
```

Comment: Very nice. I actually tried to assign to `__class__` but this seems to work with dynamically created classes only. This is the solution I was hoping for, thanks.

Comment: Nice! _Directly_ from `object` is the key iirc; the standard workaround is to define `class object(object): pass`.

Comment: I stumbled it a bit as I wanted the `Gentleman` class override a property of the `Person` class. For that case I switched the order to `type('GentlePerson',(Gentleman,Person),{})`. Hope that doesn't bring any evil.

Comment: @neo: That's fine. `Gentleman` is not a subclass of `Person`, nor vice versa, so either one can come first in the list of bases.

Comment: Is there also a way to help type checkers understand what is going on so they don't complain when they see the calls to `introduce_self`?

Comment: Answering my own question: In some situations a simple solution like `assert isinstance(p, Gentleman)` can be sufficient to help type checkers.

Answer (score 23):

Slightly cleaner version:

```
def extend_instance(obj, cls):
    """Apply mixins to a class instance after creation"""
    base_cls = obj.__class__
    base_cls_name = obj.__class__.__name__
    obj.__class__ = type(base_cls_name, (base_cls, cls),{})
```

Comment: nice solution. I'm using this to override methods on existing instances, in which case the type order should be `(cls, base_cls)`

Answer (score 8):

Although it's already answered, here is a function:

```
def extend(instance, new_class):
    instance.__class__ = type(
          '%s_extended_with_%s' % (instance.__class__.__name__, new_class.__name__), 
          (instance.__class__, new_class), 
          {},
          )
```

Comment: It is good to have a working solution but please remember this use of black magic should be well pondered, as it may be the path to the hell of hard-to-understand and hard-to-debug code.